# Why does the ESV say the tree withered from the top down, while other translations say the tree withered from the roots up?

Tags: translation-philosophy, mark, bible-versions

I was comparing translations when I noticed this difference in Mark 11:20-21.

> As they passed by in the morning, they saw the **fig tree withered away to its roots**. And Peter remembered and said to him, “Rabbi, look! The fig tree that you cursed has withered.” - ESV
>
> As they were passing by in the morning, they saw the **fig tree withered from the roots up**. Being reminded, Peter said to Him, “Rabbi, look, the fig tree which You cursed has withered.” - NASB
>
> Now in the morning, as they passed by, they saw the **fig tree dried up from the roots**. And Peter, remembering, said to Him, “Rabbi, look! The fig tree which You cursed has withered away.” - NKJV

My question is simple. From the last two translations, it is clear that the intended meaning of the passage is that the  fig dried up starting at the roots and moving upwards. So why does the ESV choose to render the passage in a way that seems to reverse this, suggesting that the plant withered from the top down instead?

Comment: Perhaps it is an idiom that means that the tree withered from top to bottom. Indicating that it was not just the leaves that faded but also the roots indicating that the plant was completely dead and not just ailing. Hence, no more would anyone eat fruit from that tree. Apparently the context suggests that the tree refers to the temple slash old covenant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Mark 11:20, the operative Greek word is "ek" which BDAG give three meanings to:

1. marker denoting separation, *from, out of, away from*.
2. marker denoting the direction from which something comes
3. marker denoting origin, cause, motive, reason, *from, of*.

BDAG then suggests that in Mark 11:20, the meaning is #2 above, "from its roots".

However, while this this is the literal meaning, I would not press the Greek too literally - I suggest the idiomatic meaning is simply, the fig tree had completely withered in its entirety, and thus totally dead and not just dead and withered leaves as is often normal out of season.